Problems while installing Wi-Fi 6 ax200 driver
Hi I have a question in this problem.
My desktop moniter resolution is weird, so I fixed it once, and the Wi-Fi is disconnected and it says "NO Wi-Fi adapter found."
First of all, when I tried to install the driver, I learned through Google that firmware and modules must be installed together. But there was one problem. The firmware appears to be installed, but the command does not work when you try to load the module.
What should I do in this situation?
I checked the https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/AX200-unable-to-detect-WiFi-Network/m-p/1225944 provided by Intel, I found 46,48,50,53,55,59,62,63,66,67,68,71,72,73.ucode exists in the /lib/firmware file, but i didn't use the 'mokutil' method. Is it okay if I try this method?
Or I looked for other ideas.
When I checked $dpkg -l | grep linux-modules , there are currently modules that are the same as the Linuxkernel version. Then, isn't it installed? However, there was no extra module. So, is this the problem?
(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:/usr$ ls
bin games lnclude lib lib32 lib64 libexec libx32 local sbin share src
(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:/usr$ cd lib
(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:/usr/lib$ ls
~~~ firmware ~~~
(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:/usr/lib$ cd firmware/
(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:/usr/lib/firmware$ ls
iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode iwlwifi-100-5.ucode ~~~ iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode 
iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode iwlwifi-cc-a0-53.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode iwlwifi-cc-a0-59.ucode iwlwifi-cc-a0-62.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-63.ucode iwlwifi-cc-a0-66.ucode iwlwifi-cc-a0-67.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-68.ucode iwlwifi-cc-a0-71.ucode iwlwifi-cc-a0-72.ucode 
iwlwifi-cc-a0-73.ucode iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0.pnvm iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm 
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm ~~~
(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ which mokutil
/usr/bin/mokutil
(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:/usr/bin$ cd mokutil
bash: cd: mokutil: Not a directory

(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ lsmod | grep iwlwifi
(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ dpkg -l | grep linux-modules
rc linux-modules-5.13.0-44-generic 5.13.0-44.49~20.04.1 amd64 Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
~
ii linux-modules-6.2.0-32-generic 6.2.0-32~32.22.04.1 amd64 Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii linux-modules-6.2.0-35-generic 6.2.0-35~35.22.04.1 amd64 Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
~
rc linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-31-generic 6.2.0-31.31~22.04.1 amd64 Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-32-generic 6.2.0-32.32~22.04.1 amd64 Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
~~
(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ nmcli dev wifi list
(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
86:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW [8086:0084]
ae:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port A [8086:2030] (rev 07)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ uname -r
6.2.0-35-generic
(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ lsb_release -a
NO LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: ubuntu 
Description: Ubunu 22.04.2 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: Jammy
(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
[sudo] password for sohyeon:
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter(see dmesg)

(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ apt search iwlwifi
backport-iwlwifi-dkms/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security 9858-0ubuntu3.3 all [upgradable from: 8324-0ubuntu3~20.04.5]
 iwlwifi driver backport in DKMS format
~
linux-modules-iwlwifi-6.2.0-34-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security 6.2.0-34.34~22.04.1 amd64 
Linux kernel iwlwifi modules for version 6.2.0-34
linux-modules-iwlwifi-6.2.0-35-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security 6.2.0-35.35~22.04.1 amd64 
Linux kernel iwlwifi modules for version 6.2.0-35
~
linux-modules-iwlwifi-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0.87.84 amd64 
Extra drivers for iwlwifi for the generic flavour
~


Your system shows a system that is badly behind on security fixes/updates, and likely using an unsupported kernel (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is using the 6.5 kernel with HWE & 5.15 if using the GA stack).  Are you using Ubuntu? or if you are, why have you not applied security fixes for so long (details imply since October 2023 if correct)  OR are you using a Ubuntu-based system??

What you mean is that it is likely to be a security issue? Then, proceed with the update 6.2.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC -> 6.5.0-28-generic (6.5.0-28.29~22.04.1) ?

The 6.2 kernel was from 23.04 which is EOL... thus Ubuntu 22.04 LTS users using the HWE kernel stack were moved to the 6.5 kernel (from 23.10) before the EOL of 23.04 occurred.   Your details show you well behind on applying security fixes OR using a Ubuntu-based system that has a lower security standard  (thus is happy to use unsupported & unsafe security wise code).  If your machine is offline it won't matter though.  5.15 is the GA kernels tack of 22.04; 6.5 current HWE.

I've tried updating the kernel, but I've encountered a problem and it's not updating. What should I do in this case? This is a question I just posted.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1511399/ubuntu-kernel-update-issue
