ubuntu kernel update issue
I try kernel update with 6.2.0-35 -> 6.5.0-28
However, there was a problem.
(base)sohyeon@X11DAi-N:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for sohyeon:
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1) focal InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1) focal Release
 Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign:3 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:4 http://cdn.oxfodnanoportal.com/apt bionic-stable InRelease
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubunutu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:6 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:7 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Ign:8 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:3 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubunutu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://cdn.oxfodnanoportal.com/apt bionic-stable InRelease
Ign:6 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:7 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Ign:8 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:3 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubunutu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://cdn.oxfodnanoportal.com/apt bionic-stable InRelease
Ign:6 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:7 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Ign:8 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:3 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
 Temporary failure resolving 'kr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubunutu jammy-security InRelease
 Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://cdn.oxfordnanoportal.com/apt bionic-stable InRelease
 Temporary failure resolving 'cdn.oxfordnanoportal.com'
Err:6 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu 
 Temporary failure resolving 'kr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:7 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubunutu focal-updates InRelease
 Temporary failure resolving 'kr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:8 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
 Temporary failure resolving 'kr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package listes...Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1) focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Is it convenient to download the package from the site in this case?
https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/kernel/

Does this answer your question? apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error

Does this answer your question? Problem with sudo apt get update: The repository cdrom... does not have a Release file

You have a focal cdrom source and a bionic ppa on your jammy system.
